# prestashop/nginx multi lang "no input file specified" on index.php request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, prestashop

we have prestashop running smoothly on nginx;

when we enabled multi language on the site, the below issue is faced:

usually after payment, without multi lang, you are redirected back to this page:
http://www.domain.com/index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart=21293&id_module=83&key=e1dbc21a0e7a8c04910968

on our apache environemnt, this works well

on nginx,
what happened when multi language was enabled is when you reach the above link, the lang parameter is added to the url (when it should not):

http://www.domain.com/en/index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart=21293&id_module=83&key=e1dbc21a0e7a8c049109689ecf36499b

or

http://www.domain.com/fr/index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart=21293&id_module=83&key=e1dbc21a0e7a8c049109689ecf36499b

which causes the user to fall on a prestashop error "input file not specified"

the above redirection should not happen, once an order is done, the following URL must work without redirection nor adding the 'en' or 'fr' code before index.php:

http://www.domain.com/index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart=21293&id_module=83&key=e1dbc21a0e7a8c049109689ecf36499b

the nginx configuration is as follows:

```
    location /favicon {
            alias /var/www/vhosts/11footballclub.com/httpdocs/img/facicon.ico;
    }

      location / {
          index index.html index.htm index.php;


    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      }

      location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
          access_log        off;
          log_not_found     off;
          expires           360d;
      }

      location ~ /\. {
          access_log off;
          log_not_found off;
          deny all;
      }

      location = /favicon.ico {
          log_not_found off;
          access_log off;
      }

      location = /robots.txt {
          allow all;
          log_not_found off;
          access_log off;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/vhosts/11footballclub.com/httpdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE max_execution_time=180;
      }

      # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
      location ~ /\. {
          deny all;
          access_log off;
          log_not_found off;
      }



      rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;

      rewrite "^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(.*)\.jpg$" /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/c/([_a-zA-Z-]+)/(.*)\.jpg$" /img/c/$1.jpg last;

      rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1-$2.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
     rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;


    #rewrite "^/index.php\?controller=http(.*)$" $1 last;


      rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-(\P{M}\p{M}*)+\.html(.*)$" /index.php?controller=product&id_product=$1$3 last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=category&id_category=$1$3 last;
      rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\.html(.*)$" /index.php?controller=product&id_product=$2$4 last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=supplier&id_supplier=$1$3 last;
      rewrite "^/([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=manufacturer&id_manufacturer=$1$3 last;
      rewrite "^/content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=cms&id_cms=$1$3 last;
      rewrite "^/content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(.*)$" /index.php?controller=cms&id_cms_category=$1$3 last;

    rewrite "^/module/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$" /index.php?fc=module&module=$1&controller=$2 last;



      rewrite ^/page-not-found$ /index.php?controller=404 last;
      rewrite ^/address$ /index.php?controller=address last;
      rewrite ^/addresses$ /index.php?controller=addresses last;
      rewrite ^/authentication$ /index.php?controller=authentication last;
      rewrite ^/best-sales$ /index.php?controller=best-sales last;
      rewrite ^/cart$ /index.php?controller=cart last;
      rewrite ^/contact-us$ /index.php?controller=contact-form last;
      rewrite ^/discount$ /index.php?controller=discount last;
      rewrite ^/guest-tracking$ /index.php?controller=guest-tracking last;
      rewrite ^/order-history$ /index.php?controller=history last;
      rewrite ^/identity$ /index.php?controller=identity last;
      rewrite ^/manufacturers$ /index.php?controller=manufacturer last;
      rewrite ^/my-account$ /index.php?controller=my-account last;

     rewrite ^/new-products$ /index.php?controller=new-products last;
      rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;
      rewrite ^/order-follow$ /index.php?controller=order-follow last;
      rewrite ^/quick-order$ /index.php?controller=order-opc last;
      rewrite ^/order-slip$ /index.php?controller=order-slip last;
      rewrite ^/password-recovery$ /index.php?controller=password last;
      rewrite ^/prices-drop$ /index.php?controller=prices-drop last;
      rewrite ^/search$ /index.php?controller=search last;
      rewrite ^/sitemap$ /index.php?controller=sitemap last;
      rewrite ^/stores$ /index.php?controller=stores last;
      rewrite ^/supplier$ /index.php?controller=supplier last;

      location ~* \.(gif)$ {
        expires 2592000s;
      }

      location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg)$ {
        expires 2592000s;
      }

      location ~* \.(png)$ {
        expires 2592000s;
      }

      location ~* \.(css)$ {
        expires 604800s;
      }

      location ~* \.(js|jsonp)$ {
        expires 604800s;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this location block to your config file.

```
location ~ (/lang1|/lang2)/index\.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Where `lang1` and `lang2` are languages used in your website (for example 'en', 'ru' and etc.). You can add more languages by appending `|/language_name` inside brackets.

P.s. don't forget to restart/reload your nginx server after modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of configuration that works pretty well with Nginx, PrestaShop v1.6.1.x (two languages enabled: EN/FR), PHP-FPM 7.2 and an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt.

If you copy/paste this example (in your /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder), please remember to:

1. Replace 'myshop.com' by your domain name
2. Replace 'myadminfolder' by your PrestaShop admin folder name
3. Replace '(/fr|/en)' with the language codes you are actually using
4. Generate your SSL certificate using Let's Encrypt certbot tool (optional, remove this section if you don't want to use SSL)
5. Make sure your PHP-FPM socket file is located in /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock, otherwise modify this path

Thanks @Canarius for the tip!

```
server {
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 80;
        server_name myshopname.com www.myshop.com
        root /var/www/myshopname.com/;
        index index.php index.html;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/myshopname.com.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myshopname.com.error_log;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 1;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.0;
        gzip_types application/json text/css application/javascript;

        rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

        location ~ (/fr|/en)/index\.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location /myadminfolder/ {
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/.*$ /myadminfolder/index.php last;
                }
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myshopname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myshopname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```